# How to replace specific char in a string javascripts

Tags: javascript

I would like to remove the given char if it occurred more than once.

```js
var input = "12313*12313*13";
var count = (input.match(/[*]/g) || []).length;

if (count > 1)
{
  x = 0;
  for (var i = 0, len = input.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (input[i] == '*')
    {
      if (x == 0)
      {
        x++;
        continue;
      }
      input[i] = '';
    }
  }
}

console.log(input);
```

The given char is `*` and i would like to remove the other `*` from the string.

I would like to have this output `12313*1231313`.

Comment: You cannot mutate a string, as you are trying to do with `input[i] = ''`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler solution using `lastIndexOf` and `substring`:

This solution just works with 2 occurrences:

```js
var input = "12313*12313*13";
var count = (input.match(/[*]/g) || []).length;

if (count > 1) {
  var i = input.lastIndexOf('*');
  input = input.substring(0, i) + input.substring(i + 1);
}

console.log(input);
```

This is a refactor of the previous one which works with N occurrences:

```js
var input = "12313*12313*13*12*13232*12312";
var count = (input.match(/[*]/g) || []).length;
var i;

while(count > 1) {
  i = input.lastIndexOf('*');
  input = input.substring(0, i) + input.substring(i + 1);
  count--;
}

console.log(input);
```

Comment: This will only remove a single following asterisk.

Comment: @torazaburo that is what i want

Comment: @torazaburo You are right, the question is not clear enough so I am not sure what he needs. Anyway I added a refactored version to remove all occurrences. Thanks!

Comment: Or something like `var first = input.indexOf('*'); if(first!=-1) input = input.substr(0, first+1) + input.substr(first+1).replace(/\*/g,'')` avoids the loop.

Comment: @ShiftN'Tab Your question said * if it occurred more than once*. Three times is "more than once". Please clarify your question, to say something like "the second occurrence only", or "the second and succeeding occurrences".

Comment: Oh i missed read you comment, sorry for that